# webpack import from folder exclude unnecessary modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I have been researching this for a while, but couldn't find any solutions for this.

I have seen this setup in many places that imports from a directory:

> import {foo} from './utilities/';

Then the webpack resolver will find the index.js in the directory (by default). 
But if I have many files in the utilities, and the export in index.js is a lot of functions, say, in utilities/index.js, the export are multiple functions:

```
export {default as foo} from './foo.js'
export {default as bar} from './bar.js';
```

Then after webpack bundles the js, both foo.js and bar.js are bundled.

I could redefine the import like

> import foo from './utilities/foo.js'
>   Then the webpack won't bundle bar.js.

I am just wondering if there is a plugin that can do this smartly and know that I don't need bar.js so that it exclude bar.js from the bundle.

Thanks

Comment: I think you want this plugin : https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/, couple with bundle-loader or promise-loader